# Why are there disabled buttons in HighStock Range Selector?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having an issue with rangeSelector in HighCharts/HighStocks. For some reason,  selections are disables. My question is this, how can I make sure that all range selection buttons are active since data is available for a specific range. Here is a  example.     [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0sw6ssof/1/)

```
$(function() {

    var seriesOptions = [], seriesCounter = 0, names = ['t1'];
    function createChart() {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            loading: {
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: 'silver'
                },
                labelStyle: {
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            yAxis : {
                            plotLines : [ {
                    value : 0,
                    width : 2,
                    color : 'silver'
                } ]
            },

            plotOptions : {
            },

            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2
            },
            series : seriesOptions
        });
    }

$.each(names, function(i, name) {

$.getJSON('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34899000/data.json?dt=' + name.toLowerCase(), function(
                data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name : name,
                data : data

            };
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enable the range selector buttons, so in your case you must add an attribute `allButtonsEnabled` and set it to `true`

```
rangeSelector: {
    allButtonsEnabled: true,
    selected: 1
},
```

See documentation
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector

> allButtonsEnabled: Boolean
>   Since 2.0.3
>
> Whether to enable all buttons from the start. By default buttons are
>   only enabled if the corresponding time range exists on the X axis, but
>   enabling all buttons allows for dynamically loading different time
>   ranges. Defaults to false.

In your fiddle enabling all buttons doesn't do anything since the time axis is 1 month which is the minimum range.